# Is there a shorthand to loop through all objects within objects with underscore?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In underscore or pure javascript, is there a shorthand for

```
_.each(data.data, function(user){
  _.each(user.apilog, function(event){
  //the stuff
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

What about somethign like this (untested).

This relies on [pluck](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) and [chaining](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining)

```
_(data.data)
    .pluck('apilog')
    .each(function(event) {
      //the stuff
    });
```

I kind of doubt it would be more efficient - but it looks a little nicer!